# React router v4 breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, breadcrumbs, react-router-v4

I am trying to implement [React Router Breadcrumbs for v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dynamic-breadcrumbs)

Following are my routes:

```
    const routes = {
      '/': 'Home',
      '/page1': 'Page 1',
      '/page2': 'Page 2'
    };
```

I could put the breadcrumbs using this library in my application, however I am having following questions:

**Que. #1:**

When I click on `Home` in my breadcrumbs, I can see the URL changes to `http://localhost:8080` However, browser still shows the same page I am on.

**Que. #2:**

When I navigate to Page2 from Page1, `url` changes from `http://localhost:8080/page1` to `http://localhost:8080/page2`.

So the breadcrumbs shown changes to `Home / Page 2` instead of changing like `Home / Page 1 / Page 2`

I know this may be because the `url` just has `/page2` after hostname. But, can I achieve the display like: `Home / Page 1 / Page 2`?

Below is the code in my main `App.jsx`:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Link to="/"><div className="routerStyle"><Glyphicon glyph="home" /></div></Link>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
    <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

and if I use like belowto cater for breadcrumbs, then my page2 gets rendered below page1 stuff:

```
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/"><div className="routerStyle"><Glyphicon glyph="home" /></div></Link>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
        <Route path="/page1/page2" component={Page2}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

***Answer:***

**Que. #1:** No need to wrap `<Breadcrumbs ..../>` element inside `<Router>` element inside each Component of application. This may be because, inclusion of `<Router>` element inside each Component leads to "nesting" of `Router` elements (note we have `Router` tag in landing page as well); which does not work with `react router v4`.

**Que. #2:** Refer to answer formally marked here (answered by *palsrealm* below)

Comment: any react codes?

Comment: Its same as the URL given in question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breadcrumbs are based on links and they work as designed. To display the pages, you need to set up a `Switch` with `Route`s in it which would load the appropriate components when the path changes. Something like

```
<Switch> 
    <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/page1' component={Page1}/>
    <Route path='/page2' component={Page2}/>
</Switch>
```

If you want the breadcrumb to show `Home/Page1/Page2` your `routes` should be `'/page1/page2' : 'Page 2'`. The `Route` should also change accordingly.

Edit: Your `Router` should be

```
 <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/"><div className="routerStyle"><Glyphicon glyph="home" /></div></Link>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
        <Route path="/page1/page2" component={Page2}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: I do not think that is something you will get out of the box. You would have to implement the logic yourself; maybe by storing the last url visited and adding it to the breadcrumbs manually using a Link or NavLink component.

Comment: @palsrealm is right. You need a `Switch`. Also, if you want to capture _both_ '/page1' and '/page1/page2', you'll need `exact` on the route for '/page1'.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code for the `Router` that you would want to use. Exactly as specified by @Luke M Willis

Comment: Thanks, now with use of "exact", the problem of having both pages render in one screen is resolved. However, when I click on breadcrumb, just the browser URL changes but not the contents. Any clue?

Comment: when the browser url changes as expected, this means your links are working fine. When the contents do not render, this means the component that is supposed to render at that url is not rendering and you need to check the component and the route.

Comment: Worked, I have explained solution to problem #1 faced, in my updated question above

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished with a HOC which would allow you to use a route config object to set breadcrumbs instead. I've open-sourced it [here](https://github.com/icd2k3/react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc), but the source code is below as well:

`Breadcrumbs.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withBreadcrumbs } from 'withBreadcrumbs';

const UserBreadcrumb = ({ match }) =>
  <span>{match.params.userId}</span>; // use match param userId to fetch/display user name

const routes = [
  { path: 'users', breadcrumb: 'Users' },
  { path: 'users/:userId', breadcrumb: UserBreadcrumb},
  { path: 'something-else', breadcrumb: ':)' },
];

const Breadcrumbs = ({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <div>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb, path, match }) => (
      <span key={path}>
        <NavLink to={match.url}>
          {breadcrumb}
        </NavLink>
        <span>/</span>
      </span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default withBreadcrumbs(routes)(Breadcrumbs);
```

`withBreadcrumbs.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { matchPath, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const renderer = ({ breadcrumb, match }) => {
  if (typeof breadcrumb === 'function') { return breadcrumb({ match }); }
  return breadcrumb;
};

export const getBreadcrumbs = ({ routes, pathname }) => {
  const matches = [];

  pathname
    .replace(/\/$/, '')
    .split('/')
    .reduce((previous, current) => {
      const pathSection = `${previous}/${current}`;

      let breadcrumbMatch;

      routes.some(({ breadcrumb, path }) => {
        const match = matchPath(pathSection, { exact: true, path });

        if (match) {
          breadcrumbMatch = {
            breadcrumb: renderer({ breadcrumb, match }),
            path,
            match,
          };
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      });

      if (breadcrumbMatch) {
        matches.push(breadcrumbMatch);
      }

      return pathSection;
    });

  return matches;
};

export const withBreadcrumbs = routes => Component => withRouter(props => (
  <Component
    {...props}
    breadcrumbs={
      getBreadcrumbs({
        pathname: props.location.pathname,
        routes,
      })
    }
  />
));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following component should return a breadcrumb at any depth, except on the home page (for obvious reasons). You won't need *React Router Breadcrumb*. My first public contribution, so if I'm missing an essential part, it would be great if somebody could point it out. I added `&raquo;` for crumbs splits, but you can obviously update that to match what you need.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
// styles
require('./styles/_breadcrumbs.scss')

// replace underscores with spaces in path names
const formatLeafName = leaf => leaf.replace('_', ' ')

// create a path based on the leaf position in the branch
const formatPath = (branch, index) => branch.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')

// output the individual breadcrumb links
const BreadCrumb = props => {
  const { leaf, index, branch } = props,
    leafPath = formatPath(branch, index),
    leafName = index == 0 ? 'home' : formatLeafName(leaf),
    leafItem =
      index + 1 < branch.length 
        ? <li className="breadcrumbs__crumb">
          <Link to={leafPath}>{leafName}</Link>
          <span className="separator">&raquo;</span>
        </li>
        : <li className="breadcrumbs__crumb">{leafName}</li>
  // the slug doesn't need a link or a separator, so we output just the leaf name

  return leafItem
}

const BreadCrumbList = props => {
  const path = props.match.url,
    listItems =
      // make sure we're not home (home return '/' on url)
      path.length > 1
      && path
        // create an array of leaf names
        .split('/')
        // send our new array to BreadCrumb for formating
        .map((leaf, index, branch) => 
          <BreadCrumb leaf={leaf} index={index} branch={branch} key={index} />
        )

  // listItem will exist anywhere but home
  return listItems && <ul className="breadcrumbs">{listItems}</ul>
}

const BreadCrumbs = props => 
  <Route path="/*" render={({ match }) => <BreadCrumbList match={match} />} />


export default BreadCrumbs
```